# Monaco editor AutoIndent disable

Tags: monaco-editor

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     editor.updateOptions({'autoIndent': 'none'}); 
});
```

This code is not working.
Am I using it wrong?
someone please help me.

Comment: referenced : https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/enums/monaco.editor.EditorAutoIndentStrategy.html#None
This is vscode issue : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5446

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!!
This works very well.

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
value: "function hello(){\nalert('Hello world!');}",
language: "javascript",
"autoIndent": 'none',
"formatOnPaste": true,
"formatOnType": true
});
```